# What functions can I use to track subscriptions?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am struggling to make a spreadsheet which will help me take control of member's subscription fees. Fees are paid per month.

[image: Example spreadsheet]

- The spreadsheet has 12 horizontal cells, each one for a different month of the year. I created a 13th one in which I want to import a function that calculates the total amount of money the member owes based on current month.
- I would also like to have each cell of the month that is not paid, to be colored red.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You say "member's", so is this for tracking only a single person? If not, if tracking lots of members, you really want to be considering a database-backed app instead of a spreadsheet.

Comment: Why is `M17` 100? Shouldn't it be 120?

Answer (score 0):

The amount that a person owes for the current year, based on the current month, is

```
=MONTH(TODAY()) * monthly_dues
```

This assumes that the member has been a member all year and that his account
was even at the end of the previous year. 
To get a formula that works in other years (stored in `A3`), use

```
=IF(A3<YEAR(TODAY()), 12, IF(A2>YEAR(TODAY()), 0, MONTH(TODAY()))) * monthly_dues
```

This gets trickier if the dues vary over time.

Answer (score 0):

> I would also like to have each cell of the month that is not paid, to be colored red.

use conditional formatting to do this.

> The spreadsheet has 12 horizontal cells, each one for a different month of the year. I created a 13th one in which I want to import a function that calculates the total amount of money the member owes based on current month.

I don't understand this one well, does the picture showing only one person's paying or the amount of people that subscribes. you can try use column() function to get the column of a cell to calculate the month of that cell.